# How to setup a countdown timer on a service for 24/7

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

I recently just learned and developed a widget. I understand that the widget have an auto update at every 30 - 60 minutes minimum. Now I have been asked to reduced that auto update to 5 minutes.

So I have thought up for creating another `Service Thread` that is constantly running a countdown timer every 5 minutes and refreshes the app to check for any possible errors. These errors are actually ping tests results. If a server is down, I will execute a `Toast Message` to inform the user that this server is down.

So, how should I go about doing this? Or is there a better suggestion. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this helps you:

Buddy use `TimerTask` to call after specific time interval

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(),1, TimeInterval);
```

and

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() 
           {        
              // code here
           }

        }
```

**Or You can Use `AlaramManager` also:**

Set `AlarmManager` like this:

```
private static final int REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 60; //repeat every 60 seconds

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Change `AlarmManager.RTC` to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` if u want to wake up phone when it goes off. More about AlarmManager [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Those two parameters also means that your alarm time will be `System.currentTimeMilis()` which is time in UTC.

Comment: Welcome Buddy.. i have added some more code so that you can have one more option i.e `AlaramManager`

Answer (score 0):

I think better use **runnable** with **postDelayed**, like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new CustomRunnable();

private class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            // your logic
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, REFRESH_TIME);
        }
    }
```

REFRESH_TIME — your constant to refresh in millis. Just run once **handler.postDelayed(runnable, REFRESH_TIME);** where you want.

Comment: What about power-saving modes, battery life and so on? (OTOH, I don't know what your device is.)

Comment: Second case use Alarm Manager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), but i think is less convenient.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mention in my question. I was thinking along the Alarm clock idea since they have a countdown timer. Thanks for the Alarm Manager suggestion.